# How to find out if an interface is implemented?

Tags: haxe

How can I find out if an object implements an interface? In other words I need a possibility to check if an object can be cast to a specific type (e.g. a specific interface).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Std.is()`](https://api.haxe.org/Std.html?#is). Or use a [safe cast](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-cast-safe.html) and it will throw an error if it fails.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to create the object and catch with a class not found exception i guess.

Comment: i want to check an **existing** object, if it implements an interface. i can do a cast and catch an exception, but that can't be the ultimate answer...